# NVD3 /D3 line chart(in bootstrap popover ) getting cut in chrome working well in firefox

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular-ui-bootstrap, nvd3.js, linechart

Showing charts in Bootstrap popover directive. I am providing height and width.

It is working as anticipated in Firefox but in Chrome its getting cut. Once I am play around with chart it would re-size to my given height and width. Anyone has idea what must be wrong. I am using ng-repeat as i may have multiple chart in popover.

below is HTML.

div class="chartHolder" ng-repeat="**chart** in rawdata"

nvd3-line-chart data='**chart**' **width="425" height="400"** showXAxis="true" showYAxis="true" tooltips="true" interactive="true" useInteractiveGuideline="true" yaxislabel ="Form Y" yaxislabeldistance = "35" legendradiobuttonmode="false" xaxislabel ="Form X" isArea="false" transitionDuration= "350" showLegend="true" objectEquality="true" margin="{left:50,top:25,bottom:50,right:40}">

/nvd3-line-chart

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that since the chart is not on the screen when the page loads, so it has a width and height of 0.

When the popover appears, even though the width is 425 and height is 400, the chart still thinks it is width 0 and height 0 until you move the page in which it resizes and gains the correct size.

The trick I have used in the past is using an ng-if directive to force the chart to instantly render to the correct width and height and never be set to 0 height and 0 width.  This works because ng-if makes sure the chart never is in the DOM when it resolves false.

So just make a boolean that determines whether a chart is shown or not and then use ng-if to hide/show the chart.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i could not achieve with your technic but what i could figure out that display:inline-block is culprit. I am giving this style to class"chartHolder" as my requirement is to show chart side by side. Removing this sytle chart render as anticipated but i need this style then only i will be able to show side by side.